# How to check if a function is injective when there are no simple examples?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Suppose I need to check if this function has inverse: $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $x(x^2-1)$

A function have inverse function if is injective and surjective, i.e is as bijective function.

Its a cubic function, then its range is $\mathbb{R}$, therefore is surjective.

Now i need to check if is injective. That is: $x_1(x_1^2 - 1) = x_2(x_2^2 -1)$, If i can find an example where this is true and $x_1 \neq x_2$ i'll can say that isn't injective, but it has taken me a long time to find a counterexample, which was $x_1 = 1 $and $x_2 = -1$.

Imagine I have a more complex function, something like

$f(x) = \frac{x^7+x^3-x+7}{x^4}$

If we plot any function is simple, make a line parallel to the axis of the abscissa and if it touches two or more points of the function it is determined that it is not injective.

But what about the functions that we cannot graph easily? What is the algebraic method to determine if a function is injective without being tediously looking for counterexamples in functions that require a very long calculation?

Obviously keep in mind that I am still a school student and I have no knowledge of calculus. However, if the only general method for this requires calculus, I am open to learn it. Thanks in advance.

PD1: With some polynomials like $x^3-x= f(x)$, I can find the solutions,that in this case are $x=\{0,-1,1\}$ And say that $f(0) = f(1) = f(-1)$ Then is not injective, but i don't know if this works for all polynomials with constant values or of higher degree.

Comment: What happens with x = 0 and x = 1?

Comment: Mark S. I don't know that.

Comment: William Elliot, i know what are the solutions for that example, i want a general method

Comment: I think you're going to have trouble finding a general method that isn't either calculus, or calculus in disguise somehow.

Comment: A continuos injective function on an interval or the real line is strictly monotonic and that is much easier to check